# Remove iOS application from share suggestions

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Currently I'm developing share extension for my iOS application and I faced the next problem: I see my application in Google Photos:

[image]

The most strange that extension doesn't work for items from Google Photos, but user is still able to see it there. I use the following subquery:

```
SUBQUERY (
    extensionItems,
    $extensionItem,
    SUBQUERY (
        $extensionItem.attachments,
        $attachment,
        ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.item"
    ).@count == 1
).@count == 1
```

As you see, I may import to my application only one item, but my app is still available for two and items (see on the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2zJ2.jpg), there are 11 items selected). Could you help me with this issue?

UPDATED: in logs I see the following message from Google Photos:

```
Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.WebContent: 113: Could not find specified service
```